# Match a column from a column with concatenated values in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a column that has concatenated values like this

```
Table CHILD:

    ChildId       Values
    2           x123,j455
    3           f456,z789 
    4           m333,y567
    5           x123,h888
```

And I have a master table MASTER that has

```
Table MASTER:

    MainValues
    x123
    f456
    y567
```

I need to get a query that'll select the following data

```
ChildId MainValues
2       x123
3       f456
4       y567
5       x123
```

Basically match value from MASTER in child values and return only the master value. How can I do this ? I have tried IN and LIKE clause matching with second table but that doesnt help much since the values are csv. Is there a way to split and match in sqlite ?

EDIT: Table and column names are fictional and intended just to explain this question better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
SELECT ChildId,MainValues FROM CHILD INNER JOIN MASTER WHERE ','||[Values]||',' like '%,'||MainValues||',%'
```

Also, please refrain from using keywords like `values` for column names...

Comment: Thanks but I ve tried it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/084ca/4 and it doesnt work - what am I missing ?

Comment: Oh darn - you are right I was using MySql - thanks @RichardTheKiwi . Thanks Idan for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQLite doesn't have a function to find the index of a character from a string. So you have to rely on something else. Idan's method is good too but can be slower. You may try this:

```
SELECT c.childID,  m.mainvalues
FROM   CHILD c 
JOIN   MASTER m 
WHERE  m.mainvalues = substr(c.ivalues, -length(c.ivalues), 4) 
    OR m.mainvalues = substr(c.ivalues, 6);
```

I have used 4 and 6 assuming your number of characters before and after the `,`. If that's not fixed you can try:

```
SELECT c.childID,  m.mainvalues
FROM   CHILD c 
JOIN   MASTER m 
WHERE  m.mainvalues = substr(c.ivalues, -length(c.ivalues), length(m.mainvalues)) 
    OR m.mainvalues = substr(c.ivalues, length(m.mainvalues) + 2);
```